# How to continually print output inside a switch statement?

Tags: c, user-interface, arduino, switch-statement

I have been trying to continually print the PWM output of pin 3 inside the switch statement condition but it only prints once. Can I continually print it in serial monitor until it meets the second conditon? or use a while loop? or a if else ?

Here is my code I also have a code with a similar function but it uses if else but still it only prints once

```
void loop() {
    // if there's any serial available, read it:
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        int InitVal = Serial.parseInt();
        int red = Serial.parseInt();

        switch(InitVal) {
            case 1:
                if (Serial.read() == '\n') {

                    analogWrite(redPin, red);
                    Serial.println(red);
                    Serial.write(red);

                }
                break;
            case 0:
                analogWrite(redPin, 0);
                Serial.println(0);
                Serial.write(0);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'am planning to inter-phase this with a GUI . A GUI sends ascii to the arduino reads it then sends the output value to the GUI.
Example

1.GUI sends [1,123] : 1 = the trigger point for the switch statement ; 123 = PWM value.

2. Arduino receives instructions and  it prints out the pwm value
3. GUI receives pwm value and displays it

Revised code: Stuck at the last while loop maybe i could use a threading function in arduino so that the last while loop would be satisfied/dissatisfied?

```
void loop() {

  int InitVal = 0;
  // if there's any serial available, read it:
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int InitVal = Serial.parseInt();
    int red = Serial.parseInt();

    switch(InitVal) {
      case 1:
        if (Serial.read() == '\n') {
           InitVal = 1;
          //analogWrite(redPin, red);
          //Serial.println(red);
         // Serial.write(red);
       }
        break;
      case 0:
        InitVal = 0;
        //analogWrite(redPin, 0);
        //Serial.println(0);
        //Serial.write(0);
        break;
       }

      if (InitVal) /* when enabled, blink leds */ {
        delay(20);
        while (InitVal == 1) /* loop forever */{

          Serial.println(red);
          Serial.write(red);
          delay(20);
        }

    }


    }
  }
```

Comment: Where does the comma in your input go and why is it needed?

Comment: If you have tried this loop, where does it fail to meet your needs?  `Serial.available()` can restrict continuous execution depending on the rate of data coming from your device.  Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: @Lundin   https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadASCIIString I'am currently following this tutorial for the arduino code  Serial.parseInt() function to locate values separated by a non-alphanumeric character.

Comment: @ryyker I'am currently using serial monitor to send the [1,123] (csv string). What I want is if  either case 1 or 0 is satisfied it continually prints the output. In my case it only prints once and waits for another input again. So therefor I need to continually send data from the GUI to the arduino in order to print it continuously ?

Comment: As I said, if there is nothing in the serial queue,  `serial.available()` will stop execution flow.  Just as a test, Place a serial.write() at the bottom of the loop to simulate what should be coming from the Arduino.

Comment: You want to continually print the output, so this printing must be outside your loop: `while (Serial.available() > 0)`. Yet this printing must not be executed more often than every 10-100ms or it can overflow your serial buffer. (You can remember the last time you sent ; but I authorize you to add a delay in your `loop()`)

Comment: Note: to succeed in listening Serial, you should have 3 separate steps (write a function for each step) in your `loop()`. 
   1)   `newCommandHasArrived = readSerialBuffer(inRawCommand)`  
   2)   `if (newCommandHasArrived)  newParsedCommand = parseCommand(inRawCommand, cmd1, cmd2, ...)`   
   3)   `if (newParsedCommand)     executeCommand(cmd1, cmd2, ...)`

Comment: @kkewlk23 My point is, where does the comma go? Does the first parseInt discard it or is it left in the buffer? This isn't clear from the Arduino documentation.

Comment: @ryyker I've edited the code above and added the Serial.write() function.

Comment: @ArnoBozo I'll take note of that in listening serial. I'll just have to research further thank you

Comment: @Lundin Honestly I dont know what the pareseint() does the the comma but maybe this tutorial could help http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=396450.0 it says that the Parsint() is a locking functions that prevent the Arduino from doing something else until they are satisfied or this documentation for the Parseint() function https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt

Comment: Debug it and see for yourself? Isn't the library source code open?

Comment: @Lundin I am pretty sure the first parseInt reads and discards the [ char, then it reads int and stops reading when it sees comma. It lets the comma in buffer. The 2nd parseInt sees comma and discards it, then it reads the int and stops reading when it sees ] in buffer.

Comment: @ArnoBozo If you are correct, then next call will find `][` in the buffer and fail miserably from there on. Take a chance, who knows, not the "manual" at least. It would probably be easier to use a tool chain with proper documentation... or just code the UART driver yourself, since this isn't exactly rocket science.

Comment: @ArnoBozo I think I found something similar to what I want and its similar to your suggestion , a loop outside the switch statements https://pastebin.com/zK5PYK3N  . Instead of a if statement maybe I can do something to continually serial write/print

Comment: @Lundin Not exactly. The next Serial.available() will see `]\n` in its buffer. The code will timeout (1s) at each parseInt and return 0 (no Int found), yet it will have discarded `]\n` from buffer. Yet the incoming frames are not managed in the code so you always have unpredictable switch in your code.

Comment: Note: I have checked in a test program that Serial.parseInt stops reading after finding an int then a non int char , and it lets the non int char in buffer. eg: input buffer: [1,123]   --> Serial.parseInt() returns 1,  remaining buffer: ,123] .

Comment: @ArnoBozo I have revised my code above to the output that I want but its stuck at the last while loop. Is there a threading( or maybe a timer) to cater 2 while loops, 1st while loop waits for instructions the 2nd while loop performs a loop to print

Comment: You are stuck because this` while(InitVal == 1)`  is always true, InitVal is never updated.This while line must be removed,  the printing block must be put outside While Serial.available loop. Note that the definition of InitVal is inside the loop() function, so it is reinit to 0 each time you reenter in loop().

Comment: The suggestion was _not_ to add the `write` function within an infinite loop, it was to add it at the bottom of one of your existing loops to force serial traffic so when execution flow was back at the switch, you could test the loop.  As is, once the infinite while loop is entered, execution flow will never leave.  Read up on callbacks, and/or event handling, and threading.

Comment: Solved my problem thank you everyone for all of your advise and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I discarded  Serial.parseInt() function, removed the switch statments and followed  @Arno Bozo advise on serial listening while following this tutorial on http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=396450.0
I came up with what I want and here is the code

```
const int redPin = 3;
const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];
char tempChars[numChars];        // temporary array for use when parsing

      // variables to hold the parsed data
boolean newData = false;

int InitVal = 0; // change to init value or red
int red = 0;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // make the pins outputs:
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
    recvWithStartEndMarkers();
    if (newData == true) {
        strcpy(tempChars, receivedChars);
            // this temporary copy is necessary to protect the original data
            //   because strtok() used in parseData() replaces the commas with \0
        parseData();
        One();
        newData = false;
    }
    else {
      Zero();

    }
}


 ///////////////////// ///////////////////// /////////////////////
void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }

        else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}

 ///////////////////// ///////////////////// /////////////////////

void parseData() {      // split the data into its parts

    char * strtokIndx; // this is used by strtok() as an index

    strtokIndx = strtok(tempChars,",");      // get the first part - the string
    InitVal = atoi(strtokIndx); // copy it to messageFromPC

    strtokIndx = strtok(NULL, ","); // this continues where the previous call left off
    red = atoi(strtokIndx);     // convert this part to an integer

}


 ///////////////////// ///////////////////// /////////////////////
void One() {

  if (InitVal == 0){

    delay(20);
    Serial.println(0);
    delay(20);
  }      
 }
 ///////////////////// ///////////////////// /////////////////////
void Zero() {

  if (InitVal == 1){

    delay(20);
    Serial.println(red);
    delay(20);
  }      
 }
```

In Summary the code works like this

1.In serial monitor send this <1,123> : 1 = the trigger point for the switch statement ; 123 = PWM value.

2. Arduino receives instructions and it prints out the pwm value
3. If you send <0,123> it prints a zero once

Answer (score 0):

I post a refined code here. The architecture may be reused for serial treatment. I have written it as an example for people I meet and who are learning with arduino.

I have made comments and explanation of ways to avoid delay. Here it is used to print current value of pwm every 1s, without stopping with a delay(1000).

```
#include <Arduino.h>

// with schedule(f,i) , the function f() will be called every i ms
//   schedule(f,i)   lines are put in loop()  function
//   f is of type   void f(void)
#define schedule(f,i) {static unsigned long l=0;unsigned long c=millis();if((unsigned long)(c-l)>=i){l=c;f();}}

const int ledPin = 13;

void setup()   {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

boolean newCommandHasArrived=false, newParsedCommand=false;
String personalSerialBuffer="";   // char[] would be better; but String are so convenient
enum ECommand {ecmdNoPwm=0, ecmdPwm=1, ecmdBad=10 };
ECommand cmd=ecmdNoPwm;
int cmdArg=0;

boolean readSerialBuffer(String &personalSerialBuffer);
boolean parseCommand(String &apersonalSerialBuffer, ECommand &acmd, int &acmdArg);
void executeCommand(ECommand acmd, int &acmdArg);
void printCurrentValue()  {Serial.println(String("cval:") + cmdArg);}


void loop() {
    // transfer serial buffer in personal buffer
    newCommandHasArrived = readSerialBuffer(personalSerialBuffer);

    if (newCommandHasArrived)   {
        newCommandHasArrived = false;
        newParsedCommand = parseCommand(personalSerialBuffer, cmd, cmdArg);
    }

    if (newParsedCommand)   {
        newParsedCommand = false;
        executeCommand(cmd, cmdArg);
    }

    // I print current value every 1000ms
    //delay(1000);    // you can often use delay without pb, but it is a bad usage
    // Here I provide you with a quick way to execute a task every 1000ms
    {
        const unsigned long  delayBetweenExecution=1000;
        static unsigned long lastTime=0;
        unsigned long current = millis();
        // note that C++ says that overflow on unsigned is well defined
        // it calculates modulo arithmetic
        if ((unsigned long)(millis() - lastTime) >= delayBetweenExecution)   {
            lastTime = current;
            Serial.println(String("cval:") + cmdArg);
        }
    }

    // We can make it shorter thanks to a macro:
    //   but you have to define a void function(void)  that uses only global variable
    //   because it has no argument :
    // void printCurrentValue()  {Serial.print(String("cval:") + cmdArg);}
    //schedule(printCurrentValue, 1000);
}



boolean readSerialBuffer(String &personalSerialBuffer)   {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        personalSerialBuffer.concat(Serial.readString());
    }

    // the frame is considered finished, if it ends with \n
    if (personalSerialBuffer.endsWith("\n"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

boolean parseCommand(String &apersonalSerialBuffer, ECommand &acmd, int &acmdArg)   {
    // format [ 1, 123]\n
    // I omit [  then I read first int : 1
    // Note: I cannot detect if no int is found because it will return 0 that is a valid cmd
    int readCmd = apersonalSerialBuffer.substring(1).toInt();

    // conversion readCmd to acmd
    switch (readCmd)   {
    case 0:
        acmd = ecmdNoPwm;   break;
    case 1:
        acmd = ecmdPwm;   break;
    default:
        Serial.println(String("new command unknown: ") +
                       apersonalSerialBuffer);
        apersonalSerialBuffer = "";
        return false;
    }

    // find beginning of 2nd part, separated by ','
    int sepPos = apersonalSerialBuffer.indexOf(',');
    // no ',' : indexOf returns -1
    if (sepPos == -1)   {
        Serial.println(String("new command could not be parsed: ") +
                       apersonalSerialBuffer);
        apersonalSerialBuffer = "";
        return false;
    }
    // Note: I cannot detect if no int is found because it will return 0 that is a valid cmd
    acmdArg = apersonalSerialBuffer.substring(sepPos+1).toInt();

    // All is fine
    // I have to reset buffer before leaving
    apersonalSerialBuffer = "";
    return true;
}

void executeCommand(ECommand acmd, int &acmdArg)   {
    switch(acmd)   {
    case ecmdNoPwm:
        // I erase acmdArg
        acmdArg = 0;
        analogWrite(ledPin, acmdArg);
        Serial.println("cmd no pwm");
        break;
    case ecmdPwm:
        analogWrite(ledPin, acmdArg);
        Serial.print("cmd pwm:");  Serial.println(acmdArg);
        break;
    default:
        analogWrite(ledPin, 0);
        Serial.println("Bad cmd");
    }
}
```